# Running from USB flash drive and can't install teamviewer

Tags: software-installation

I am running ubuntu from a USB flash drive and I am trying to install team viewer. I get this error message:

```
dependency is not satisfiable: ia32-libs.
```

I am not very tech savvy, can you help?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your question =)
try to run this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

After that, the TeamViewer should be successfully established.